# Excel VBA Concatenate Function With COUNTIF Like Condition

Tags: vba, excel

**The duplicate that this references is asking for a formula. The person explicitly said no VBA.**

I'm looking for a function that performs concatenation like the built-in `CONCATENATE()` function, but with conditions like `COUNTIF()`.

I'm looking for a simple VBA function. Other answers are complicated formulas.

Does something like this exist?

*This question was created and worded to be found easily in a search. The idea was to help others from having to read many other questions and answers and not finding the answer they needed.*

Comment: @Jeeped The duplicate reference is asking for an Excel formula. I don't want complicated formulas. I saw that question and had I thought my answer was relevant there I would have posted. The question clearly asks for Excel formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a VBA function called ConcatenateIF() It works similar to how COUNTIF() works.

```
Function ConcatenateIf(CriteriaRange As Range, Condition As Variant, _
        ConcatenateRange As Range, Optional Separator As String = ",") As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strResult As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If CriteriaRange.Count <> ConcatenateRange.Count Then
        ConcatenateIf = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = 1 To CriteriaRange.Count
        If CriteriaRange.Cells(i).Value = Condition Then
            strResult = strResult & Separator & ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value
        End If
    Next i
    If strResult <> "" Then
        strResult = Mid(strResult, Len(Separator) + 1)
    End If
    ConcatenateIf = strResult
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ConcatenateIf = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

http://www.eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=12298